# How to assign a boolean expression condition to a variable in shell

Tags: linux, shell

I wanted to do the following in shell script.

Assign a variable CON_1 based on no. of arguments passed, later i will use this CON_1 variable in another if condition

```
if [ $# < 2 ];then
CON_1=([ $m = Online ])
else
CON_1=[ $m = Online -a ${#bld_stat} -gt 0 ]
```

Based on CON_1 variable value i'm printing a message

```
if $CON_1; then
```

I do not know whether this is possible in shell, if it is possible can someone please guide me on this.

Comment: What is this weird value you are trying to set in `CON_1`? What is `([ $m = Online ])`??

Comment: $m can be one of two values "Online/Offline"

Comment: i'm trying to assign the entire condition to Con_1.

Comment: @inian:Ultimately i want a variable to hold a full logical condition like below  "CON_1 = some logical condition". i will use this CON_1 in a if loop,like if CON1

Comment: Your requirement is unclear, you may have to add details to have a more verifiable sample input and expected o/p

Comment: hmm i need something like a macro in c, this macro will hold a logical condition like (i<=2 && j>=5), i will use this macro in a if condition.

Answer (score 4):

You can store a **result** in a variable easily:

```
[ $m = Online -a ${#bld_stat} -gt 0 ]
condition=$?
```

You can store the **source** of a condition in a variable, too, but then you need `eval` to run it:

```
condition='[ $m = Online -a ${#bld_stat} -gt 0 ]'
eval "$condition"
```

Without `eval`, variables wouldn't be expanded, as variable expansion happens only once.

Instead of a variable, use a **function**:

```
condition () {
    [ $m = Online -a ${#bld_stat} -gt 0 ]
}
if condition ; then ...
```

You can even pass arguments to functions:

```
condition () {
    [ $m = Online -a ${#bld_stat} -gt "$1" ]
}
if condition 12 ; then # Will use 12 instead of 0 to compare.
```